# Use EJS templates with sails.js

Tags: javascript, templates, sails.js, ejs

I can't figure out how to use EJS templates with the framework sails.js.

Here is what I've tried:

```
ejs = require('ejs')

new ejs({url: 'assets/linker/templates/box.ejs'}).render(data);
```

But I get `object is not a function`

Any example? I tried to follow the example here: http://embeddedjs.com/getting_started.html
But I don't understand why they ask to download the script `ejs_production.js`...

Comment: ejs is the default templating in engine in sails.js. You don't need to do any thing to start working with it.

Comment: I have found how to use client side templates, but I still don't understand how tu use them from the server side.

Comment: I can't understand your point of using them on server side..

Comment: Because I want to use a template inside another template and I prefer doing so in the server side instead.

Answer (score 6):

assets/templates is used for JST

and,

[Example](http://embeddedjs.com/getting_started.html#create_template) is used client side

---

server side include ?
https://github.com/visionmedia/ejs#includes

**views/header.ejs**

```
<header>
    <h1>title: <%- title %> </h1>
</header>
```

**views/layout.ejs**

```
<body>
<% include header %>
```

...

extends? (Japanese) ※ roundabout

http://nantokaworks.com/node-advent2013-day20/

---

Both of Server Side and Client Side ?

sorry. no idea about it...

**assets/common/header.ejs**

```
<header>
    <h1>title: <%- title %> </h1>
</header>
```

**views/layout.ejs**

```
<body>
 <% include ../assets/common/header %>
```

It may be used in both in this way...

```
new ejs({url: 'assets/common/header.ejs'}).render(data);
```

or  grunt-contrib-copy, folder views/common to assets/common

Comment: Ok, so it looks like the server side is through the `include` operator. I tried to use it yesterday but the code became invalid and the page wouldn't render, maybe wrong path. Debug EJS is a pain in the ass. I will give another try tonight.